# Detect question ban

Tags: support

I currently don't have any questions to ask. However, yesterday I asked a question that received mostly negative attention but attracted one answer that was not upvoted. Here is a link:

[Modern use of "I should think" vs. "I would think" in speech](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293875/modern-use-of-i-should-think-vs-i-would-think-in-speech)

I decided to delete it, based on having half-read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban#311812

After deleting it I read the rest of the post saying that deleting a question after someone posts an answer can lead to a stiff penalty. Is there a way I can tell if I'm penalized without asking a question?

Comment: link to deleted question (for those who can view it)?

Comment: @Mitch added it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't have an answer for the meta question about penalties. It does seem like a duplicate though. But if you really were asking about frequency of usage, then you did not make that apparent. If you had it might have been a question worth keeping.

Comment: @Mitch I asked it because it surprised me that I used it myself without going out of my way, even though say Tom Lehrer's use of a similar construction sounds strange to me. My speech has some unusual features on occasion (for example I sometimes use uncommon words to be precise), but it's mostly standard American English as far as I can tell, so I was wondering if perhaps other people do this.

Comment: I should think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this information is available to users until they try to post a question. Moderators can find out if a user on their site has triggered the ban.

I wouldn't worry about deleting one question with an answer. The temporary ban is to prevent "help vampire" behavior, where a user posts a question, gets an answer, then deletes the question and posts another one, repeating the cycle in an attempt to avoid downvotes.

The reason that behavior is problematic is that questions and answers are intended to persist in order to help future visitors. Users who post off-topic or poorly worded questions rapidly and then delete them as soon as they have an answer are adding more work for the rest of the community without providing any benefit.

That said, you do not appear to have triggered the ban. I would also like to encourage you to consider un-deleting your question. There is nothing wrong with posting a duplicate question. It means someone else thought of it already and it was a good question!

Also it doesn't appear that your question was actually closed as a duplicate, which means there is still plenty of opportunity for good answers to appear. EL&U takes longer than SO to respond, so give it some time.

Just some food for thought. You can leave it deleted if you prefer.

Comment: Sure, I'll undelete it. I'm used to math SE where the question is either answered immediately or never (an overstatement, but somewhat close to the truth). Thanks.